# Oracle SQL Developer - Dates sorted incorrectly(?)

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a simple query which is supposed to be order the results by the `von` column in descending order. The column has the datatype of `DATE`. It is an Oracle database and I'm using Oracle SQL Developer when executing the queries.

Here is the query that I am executing:

```
select * 
from billinginterval
where id = xxxx or id = yyyy
order by von desc;
```

and here are the two results I get for this query:

[image: Query Results]

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't the results appear in the reversed order? As when I execute this query

```
select von 
from billinginterval
order by von desc;
```

The [result set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yp7I.png) appears to be in the correct order.

Any help in understanding this would be much appreciated!

Comment: What do you get is you run `SELECT DUMP(von), TO_CHAR(von, 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM billinginterval`?

Comment: I'm receiving 
DUMP(VON)=: Typ=12 Len=7: 100,119,1,1,1,1,1
TO_CHAR(von, 'YYYY-MM-DD'): 0019-01-01
It was probably a wrong insert done by someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE billinginterval (id, von) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2018-09-01' FROM DUAL;

INSERT INTO billinginterval (id, von)
VALUES (3, TO_DATE('03.01.1919', 'DD.MM.YYYY'));

INSERT INTO billinginterval (id, von)
VALUES (3, TO_DATE('03.01.19', 'DD.MM.YYYY'));
```

And setup the session using:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'Germany';
```

Then the query:

```sql
select b.*,
       TO_CHAR(von, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS formatted_von
from billinginterval b
order by von desc;
```

Will output:

> | ID | VON | FORMATTED_VON |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 01.09.18 | 2018-09-01 |
> | 2 | 03.01.19 | 1919-01-03 |
> | 3 | 03.01.19 | 0019-01-03 |

The row with an `id` of 2 is probably valid data and should be in that order; however, the row with an `id` of 3 is probably invalid and someone has used an `INSERT` like:

```sql
INSERT INTO billinginterval (id, von)
VALUES (3, TO_DATE('03.01.19', 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
```

Which has the database has taken the year to be `0019` and not `2019`. You should always make sure your data input matches the expected format and do not provide a two-digit year when a four-digit year is expected.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=96bc38a383b43950d3e28e38e3391713)*

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the results were reversed because of an incorrect insert in the database. Since

```
select to_char(von, 'DD-MM-YYYY') from verrechnungszeitraum where id = xxxx;
```

returns 01-01-0019 as a result. However other rows result in proper years. Closing.

Comment: What's the point of this "Answer"? MT0 diagnosed the problem correctly, and posted an answer with full details. Your proper reaction to that should be to mark his answer as "Correct Answer", not to post a separate answer of your own. Please delete your answer, and mark the correct answer accordingly.

Comment: @mathguy I prompted the OP in comments which let them give more details and diagnose the problem themselves. While I was typing up my answer and getting the fiddle to work, they posted this short answer and then shortly after I posted my full answer with a [MRE] and details of what problems to look for in the `INSERT`s; so their answer did not come after mine.

Comment: @MT0 - OK, that makes sense. At this point, though, I would still encourage the OP to close his own answer and to mark yours as the correct answer.